# Не могу вызвать функцию _beginthread(..), c++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Хочу запустить метод в отдельном потоке при помощи функции _beginthread(..), но получаю ошибку, если не было указано void* в аргументах функции.

Вопрос: что обозначает void* в аргументах функции func2(..);

Набор инструментов платформы: Visual Studio 2019 (v142)

[image: Код]
[image: Описание ошкбки]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функцию, запускаемую отдельным потоком, можно передать указатель на какую-то информацию - этот указатель вы передаете как один из параметров в `_beginthread`, и он затем передается в функцию.

Если он вам не нужен - просто объявите свою функцию как

```
void func(void*)
{
    ...
```

просто игнорируя этот параметр.

Если вы передаете `void func()` - то *как* `_beginthread` передаст ей этот самый указатель? Она же не шаблонная все-таки, чтоб принимать разные варианты...